# How to fix broken plug

Tags: plumbing, abs

My neighbors landscaper has totally mutilated the cleanout plug between our yards that connect to each other. Can I use a brass plug in the ABS pipe, or should I use ABS to ABS. (4" pipe) whatever I use will be a flush plug.

Answer (score 1):

I think a brass plug is an excellent choice. It is all the same threads.

Answer (score 1):

Not being sure how the landscaper damaged the plug I would go with plastic again. My reason being, that what ever he did could happen again. If it was hit by a lawnmower, tractor or some other powered device the next time hit could result in damage to the pipe. You could be repairing the pipe along with any damage from the shrapnel of the damaged brass plug.